# Replace string concat with Razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

Here is my ASP.NET MVC 4 View (Razor) code:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(column =>
    {
        column.For(s => s.Description + @"<div class='results'>
            <a href='#'>Link 1</a>
            <a href='#'>Link 2</a>
        </div>").Named("Description").Encode(false);
    })
```

As you can see I am concatenating strings there. I would like to use Razor instead. Is there any simple way to do this?

Putting `<text>` instead of " doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any simple way to do this?

Sure, just use `column.Custom` instead of `column.For`:

```
column
    .Custom(
        @<text>
            <div class="results">
                <a href='#'>Link 1</a>
                <a href='#'>Link 2</a>
            </div>
        </text>
    )
    .Named("Description");
```

Comment: Cool! And how can I use item field inside Razor?

Comment: Simply use `@item.BlahBlah`. In your case I think that would be `@item.Description` or something.